# Is it a good idea to modify Magento Cutomer Model

Tags: php, magento, coding-style, design-principles

A couple of days back I posted a [question on StackExchange - Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67948/validating-is-unique-property-for-custom-attribute-in-customer-registration-form). Please read that post as this question is related.

Since, I wanted to have this newly created customer attribute Unique. i.e no user should have same attribute as another already existing user. I tried doing it my self this way :

I've modified the `_beforeSave()` function in `/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php` by adding the following code right before email verification logic.

```
$result=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mobile', $customer->getMobile())->load();

        if ( is_object($result) && count($result) >= 1)
        {
            throw Mage::exception(
                'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('There is already an account with this mobile number.'),
                Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_MOBILE_EXISTS
            );
        }
```

Doing so, I was able to throw an exception when the attribute is already associated with an existing user.

Is adding required code to Model a good idea ? Will this modification stay intact if I update Magento from admin panel ?

Also, please suggest (if any) an alternative solution to check for duplicate entry in my local module rather than editing a core Model file.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing changes in core file. So it will not work after upgrade. It is recommended to use own module for it.

You can refer following link for basic module creation.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643

Comment: This is NOT link-only.  The answer is in the first paragraph.